# Why do developers split every single part of a software into so many modules?

Tags: c++, user-interface, module, open-source, software-design

I'm having a read of other people's source code from open source projects such as Pidgin, Filezilla and various others so that I may get a brief idea how software really is written.

**I noticed that when writing GUI, they like to split the whole interface into classes.**
More or less, lots of projects I see every single bit broken down, into perhaps a total of 70 files (35cpp and 35.h).

For example: 1 listview may be an entire class, a menubar may be a class or a tabview a whole module.

And this isn't just the UI part - the network modules are also broken down by a huge amount - almost every function itself is a .cpp file.

**My question:** Is this really just preference or does it have any particular benefit?
I for example would've written the whole UI into a single module..

What is the actual reason?

Comment: Maintainability for working as a team or just to minimize errors or large amounts of code being crammed?

Comment: Smaller pieces tend to make unit testing easier as well.

Comment: In C++, I cut things into tinier pieces to make the interdepencies between modules more obvious.  If I find myself needing to `#include` too many interfaces, I start realizing that maybe I need a higher-level interface that encapsulates those, for example.  It both aids maintenance and encourages better habits, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

Some languages encourage one file per type, and people who know those languages also program in c++, and bring that habit here.

For reuse, you want thing you put into a header to be simple, orthogonal, and conceptually clean, this tends to mean avoiding files that have everything one particular project needs.

Before git/mercurial it could be a real hassle to have multiple people edit the same file. Thus separating things into lots of files help a lot with multiple people editting, both for the edits and for your version control software.

It also speed up compilation. The small the file you are editting, the less compilation is needed, so unless the linking stage is slow, small file is a very good thing.

Many people have been hurt by cramming things into a single or small numbers of files. Few people have been seriously hurt by chopping them up into 50+ files. People tend towards things that dont overtly teach you hard lessons.

Answer (score 1):

you might want to split the project into separate files to improve readability and to sometimes also make debugging easier. The filezilla project could have all been written into just two files something like main.cpp and main.h but if you do that, you will have to write tens of thousands of codes into the same file which is a very bad programming practice even though it is legal.

Comment: Well, yes I understand that, but I'd expect around a maximum of 17 files for such a project, not 70... I just find it slightly absurd.

Comment: it is though but in case of filezilla, just like vlc, it is a very big project with lots of authors because it is open source. Also they made it a multi platform project which requires extra code.

Answer (score 0):

One benefit will come from Testing. Distributing system testing throughout the design hierarchy (e.g. rather than a single physical component) can be much effective and cheaper than testing at only the highest-level interface.